# Angular Where to configure css, jss, font files to apply global stying

Tags: angular

I am learning angular and created my app. I got a few css, js, images, and font files to add and apply global styling across all components.

My first test was to apply styling to my header component which I added on

```
app.component.html
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Right now, there is no styling in my header component which is

```
<header class="my-headerStyle">
  <div class="my-header-row">

  </div>
</header>
```

When I look at the site with working styles which is using the same files I have downloaded, there are images, colored background in the header div container etc..

Only way I got the styling to be visible is copy/paste the styling from the css file to my header.component.css but that is the wrong way.

I tried the following but so far it is not working

```
index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customStyling.css" type="text/css">
<link src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link src="js/scripts.min.js">
<link src="js/jquery.min.js">

app.component.scss

@import url(../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(../assets/css/customStyling.css);
```

Any help is appreciated. The styling is located in customStyling.css but so far I am stuck

Comment: Did you take a look at the "styles" array in the angular.json https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your global styles in src=>styles.css file, Alternatively, you can create a CSS file and add its path in angular.json

Comment: Thanks for helping. Added the css files to angular.json script array and it starting working